# simpleXML parsing to PHP

Tags: php, xml, simplexml

I'm trying to grab the "5088" inside the totalSize value of this XML file, but not getting any output.

Code

```
<?php
    $xml = simplexml_load_file("http://***.com/xmlfile") or die("Failed to load");
    echo $xml->totalSize;
?>
```

XML file contents

```
<MediaContainer size="0" totalSize="5088" allowSync="1" art="/:/resources/show-fanart.jpg" identifier="com.plexapp.plugins.library" librarySectionID="3" librarySectionTitle="TV Shows" librarySectionUUID="e503e28f-c4e1-4fe3-86c9-f8a6a34b8bfe" mediaTagPrefix="/system/bundle/media/flags/" mediaTagVersion="1588691599" nocache="1" offset="0" thumb="/:/resources/show.png" title1="TV Shows" title2="All Shows" viewGroup="show" viewMode="65592"> </MediaContainer>
```

Comment: `$xml['totalSize']`. See https://www.php.net/manual/simplexml.examples-basic.php#example-6806

Comment: Make sense now! Thank you.